# How can I make my NSScroller subclass have a different width?

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to create a custom subclass of NSScroller. I have created the class, and set it as the vertical scroller on an NSScrollView in IB. When I run my project, the `drawRect:` method is called for my subclass, so I know that it is properly connected.

Now, How do I change the width of my fancy new NSScroller? No matter what I do to its bounds and frame, it always wants to draw in a rectangle 15 pixels wide (the size of the default NSScroller).

Answer (score 2):

In your NSScroller subclass, you have to override scrollerWidth:

```
+(CGFloat)scrollerWidth
{
    return 30.0;
}
```

This is the value that NSScrollView uses to define the frame for your component when it sets it up.

Comment: I have tried overriding this method, but the problem is that NSScrollview always calls this class method on NSScroller, instead of my custom subclass. There is a private _verticalScrollerClass variable in NSScrollView which can be changed, but overriding private variables is not supported.

Comment: Hmm... this may be happening because it's getting archived by IB at that (original) size. Have you tried setting it programmatically to see if that helps?

Comment: I have. Everything I have read suggests that overriding that private ivar is the only way to go. I ended up just creating my own view to duplicate scrollbar functionality and hid the default scrollbar altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You can use categories to override the scroller width method for all NSScrollers.

Eg. In NSScroller-MyScroller.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSScroller (MyScroller)

+ (CGFloat)scrollerWidth;
+ (CGFloat)scrollerWidthForControlSize: (NSControlSize)controlSize;

@end
```

In NSScroller-MyScroller.m:

```
#import "NSScroller-MyScroller.h"
#define SCROLLER_WIDTH 30.0

@implementation NSScroller (MyScroller)

+ (CGFloat)scrollerWidth {
    return SCROLLER_WIDTH;
}

+ (CGFloat)scrollerWidthForControlSize: (NSControlSize)controlSize {
    return SCROLLER_WIDTH;
}

@end
```